# Using telnet with httpbin.org, I can't return any GET request

Tags: http

I am following a course on lynda.com.  We are experimenting with sending HTTP requests by using a command-line telnet app.

However, in the video, the "teacher" is explicitly typing:

```
telnet www.httpbin.org 80
GET /ip HTTP/1.0
```

Which returns the local IP address. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, although I did exactly what he did.  When I type the `GET /ip HTTP/1.0` line, I get a `400 Bad Request` response, but the page `/ip` does exist.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does it work for the teacher in the video, but not for me?

Edit: Also, when it tried to connect to `www.httpbin.org`, I can see:

```
Trying "IP_FROM_WEBSITE"
Connected to www.httpbin.org.herokudns.com
```

The part of `.herokudns.com` is only on my side, in the video I can only see `Connected to www.httpbin.org`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the server doesn't support HTTP 1.0. Maybe the video is older and it used to.

A valid HTTP 1.1 request would look like this:

```
telnet www.httpbin.org 80
GET /ip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.httpbin.org
```

Comment: The `httpbin.org` server accepts an HTTP 1.0 request just fine (I tried it), but it requires the `Host` header be present.  I would consider this a bug on the server's part, since `Host` did not exist in HTTP 1.0, and the server is supposed to be looking at the version number specified in the request and then acting accordingly.  Most modern HTTP clients include the `Host` header, even for HTTP 1.0 requests.  It doesn't hurt 1.0, and it helps servers support virtual hosts even in 1.0.